# AWS error rate monitoring for nginx app

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring, amazon-cloudwatch

What is the best way to get error rate (errors as a proportion of responses) monitoring for an `nginx` app on an EC2 server in AWS?

I'd like an alarm if the percentage of 500 responses goes above a certain threshold, say 10%.

I have tried adding a [Cloudwatch Log Metric](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FindCountMetric.html), but that can only measure the number of 500 responses or the number of responses. I can't seem to get it to measure the percentage of responses which are errors.

Comment: What kind of application is nginx serving/proxying? Have you looked into new relic?

Comment: I've seen php script parsing logs and counting errors. So all is need to get percents is calculate amount of successful requests.